# Can my Dell Inspiron 3443 laptop run ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, dell

I have a Dell Inspiron 3443 laptop on which I want to install ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The laptop meets all the specs required for the OS, but on the official Dell support page, it is said to support only windows (7,8.1,10) and ubuntu 14.04, 12.04. I wonder if my laptop truly doesn't support the OS, or it is just that the page was not updated to include the 16.04 version. Note that I bought this computer in February 2016, and at this time ubuntu 16.04 wasn't around.

Answer (score 1):

**Test it by booting a live OS from USB**

If your machine can run 14.04, I suspect it can run 16.04 as well, but don't take my word for it. Create a bootable Ubuntu 16.04 (or any other version you want to try) USB stick, and see if it will boot! You can create this kind of USB from [Windows](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) or [Ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu). Once you have Ubuntu on your USB, you can take it for a test drive on computer as a [live OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_USB#Benefits_and_limitations) without destroying or changing the existing operating system that you currently have installed on your machine.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I gave it a try as you recommended and the OS booted just fine. It seems that my machine can really handle 16.04.